# Components of wave vector

Tags: waves, wavelength

Is 3-dimensional wave vector defined as $$ \tag{1} \mathbf{k}=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda_{x}}\mathbf{\hat{x}}+\frac{2\pi}{\lambda_{y}}\mathbf{\hat{y}}+\frac{2\pi}{\lambda_{z}}\mathbf{\hat{z}}
  ?
$$
If it is, then it's magnitude would be $$ \tag{2} |\mathbf{k}|=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{1}{\lambda_{x}^{2}}+\frac{1}{\lambda_{y}^{2}}+\frac{1}{\lambda_{z}^{2}}}
 .$$
But on the other hand, we know that the magnitude of a wave vector is given by $$ \tag{3} |\mathbf{k}|=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}.
 $$ So in order for these two to be equivalent it can't be true that $$ \tag{4} \lambda=\sqrt{\lambda_{x}^{2}+\lambda_{y}^{2}+\lambda_{z}^{2}}.$$ 
But doesn't this follow from Pythagoras's theorem so it should be true? I would guess that definition ($1$) is not true but [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box) Wikipedia article about particle in a box and its section 'Higher-dimensional boxes' seems like it uses definition ($1$). Or maybe it doesn't, but then is it not true that $$ \tag{5} \lambda_{x}=\frac{2L_{x}}{n_{x}}
 ?
 $$ If not, could you explain why?

Comment: I know. Read it more carefully.

Comment: "can't be true", sorry

Comment: I think that your edit should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equation (4) is clearly not true. Consider a simple plane wave propagating in the x direction. Then clearly we should have $\lambda = \lambda_x$. However $\lambda_y$ is infinite, so equation (4) does not work. (If you don't like the idea that $\lambda_y$ should be considered infinite, you can instead consider a wave making a small angle to the x axis, so $\lambda$ is approximately $\lambda_x$, but $\lambda_y$ is very large.)

Comment: This is incorrect! in case of a small angle you proposed $\lambda_y$ would be very small and it approaches zero as the angle approaches zero. $\lambda_y$ is projection of the wave length to y-axis and therefore can't be greater that $\lambda$.

Comment: No $\lambda_y$ is the effective wavelength in the $y$ direction, i. e. the distance you have to go in the $y$ direction for the waveform to repeat. If I draw 2 wavefronts it is the distance between their intercepts with the $y$ axis. This cannot be less than $\lambda$, but can be arbitrarily large

Comment: Yep, you're right. I had understood incorrectly what $\lambda_x$ means. The definition you explain is definitely the most natural one and the one being used.

Answer (score 3):

(1) is a definition of $\lambda_x$, $\lambda_y$ and $\lambda_z$, by identification of **k** components on your base.

(2) expresses the norm of **k**. **This** is Pythagora's theorem.

(3) is a definition of $\lambda$, from which you can calculate its value in terms of $\lambda_x$, $\lambda_y$ and $\lambda_z$.

There is no need for Pythagora's theorem to hold  in any arbitrary space like $\lambda$'s space. Indeed, you've just proved that it didn't here. It is rather the contrary: you create a Hilbert space by defining perpendicularity / dot product through the extension of Pythagora's theorem.

**Addendum after discussion with OP in the comment section**

It is not easy to define a natural length here. You have a 3D pattern which is periodic, so it lies in a rectangular parallelepiped and reproduces itself every $\lambda_x$ on $x$ axis, $_$ on $y$ axis and $_$ on $z$ axis. Rectangular parallelepiped's diagonal is not an "obvious" wavelength. Taking a kind of quadratic mean (up to a ${1 \over \sqrt{3}}$ factor) makes more or less sense. And, as @BySymmetry said, if the wave is 1D or 2D, using Pythagora would give $\lambda = \infty$ whatever the wave, which wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: So you believe that ($4$) is not true? Wave length represents physical distance so naturally Pythagoras's theorem should apply because it's just basic geometry.

Comment: @ProfessorKirby Well, it depends. Distance of what? You have a 3D pattern which is periodic, so it lies in a rectangular parallelepiped and reproduces itself every $\lambda_x$ on $x$ axis, $\lambda_y$ on $y$ axis and $\lambda_z$ on $z$ axis.  Rectangular parallelepiped's diagonal is not an "obvious" wavelength, I guess.

Comment: Taking a kind of quadratic mean (up to a ${1 \over \sqrt{3}}$ factor) makes more or less sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

From Eq.2 and Eq.3, Eq.4 should read:
$$
\frac{1}{\lambda} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{\lambda_x^2} + \frac{1}{\lambda_y^2} + \frac{1}{\lambda_z^2}}
$$ or better:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\lambda} = \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)_x^2 + \left(\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)_y^2 + \left(\frac{1}{\lambda}\right)_z^2}
\end{equation}
because $\lambda$ is not a vector, rather $\mathbf k$ is a wave vector and it has a [direction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine)  of ($k_x, k_y, k_z$) and a length of $\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$.
\begin{align}
\mathbf k = (k_x,k_y,k_z) &= (\mathbf k \cdot \hat{\mathbf x}, \mathbf k \cdot \hat{\mathbf y}, \mathbf k \cdot \hat{\mathbf z}) = \lVert\mathbf k\rVert(cos\alpha, cos\beta,cos\gamma)\\ \lVert\mathbf k\rVert &= \sqrt{k_x^2 + k_y^2 + k_z^2} = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}
\end{align}
The EM wave equation can be written as:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbf E(\mathbf r, t) &= \mathbf E_o sin(\mathbf k \cdot  \mathbf r - \omega t) \\
\mathbf E(x, y, z, t) &= \mathbf E_o sin(k_x x + k_y y + k_z z - \omega t)
\end{align}$$
The 2-D version of $\mathbf k = (k_x,k_y)$ can be used to derive the laws of reflection and refraction due to a change of the light propagation direction.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity (and because it is easier to draw), let us
consider a wave in 2-dimensional space instead of 3-dimensional space.

[image: wave]

The wave has wavelength $\lambda$.
Along the $x$-direction it has wavelength $\lambda_x$,
and along the $y$-direction it has wavelength $\lambda_y$.

Notice especially $\lambda<\lambda_x$ and $\lambda<\lambda_y$.
This obviously contradicts the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)
$\lambda^2=\lambda_x^2+\lambda_y^2$,
because then we would have $\lambda>\lambda_x$ and $\lambda>\lambda_y$.
The Pythagorean theorem is not applicable here because
$\lambda_x$, $\lambda_y$ and $\lambda$ are not the
cathetes  and *hypotenuse* of a right triangle.

However, $\lambda_x$, $\lambda_y$ and $\lambda$
are the cathetes and *height* of a right triangle.
And therefore we can apply the so-called [inverse Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Pythagorean_theorem).

> [image]
> Comparison of the inverse Pythagorean theorem with the Pythagorean theorem

<sub>(image from [Inverse Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Pythagorean_theorem))</sub>

Hence we have
$$\frac{1}{\lambda^2}=\frac{1}{\lambda_x^2}+\frac{1}{\lambda_y^2}.$$
We can now define the components and magnitude of the wave-vector $\mathbf{k}$
in the usaual way ($k_x=2\pi/\lambda_x$, $k_y=2\pi/\lambda_y$, $k=2\pi/\lambda$),
and get the Pythagorean relation for the wave-vector
$$k^2=k_x^2+k_y^2$$

---

The extension from 2-dimensional to 3-dimensional space is easy.
Just add $\lambda_z$ and $k_z=2\pi/\lambda_z$ to the reasoning above.
Then we have
$$\frac{1}{\lambda^2}=\frac{1}{\lambda_x^2}+\frac{1}{\lambda_y^2}+\frac{1}{\lambda_z^2}$$
$$k^2=k_x^2+k_y^2+k_z^2$$

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to have found out, eq. 1 is wrong, because the wavelengh is not a vector. It is a scalar.

$k=2\pi/\lambda$

for the case of a one dimensional wave.

For a higher-dimensional one, you have to consider the normal vector, that is, the unit vector that points in the direction of propagation.

$\hat{n}=(n_x, n_y, n_z)$

And it is a unit vector, so that $n_x^2+n_y^2+n_z^2=1$

Then, the wave vector is

$$\vec{k}=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda} (n_x, n_y, n_z)$$

So of course its modulus remains $2\pi/\lambda$.

Answer (score -1):

Equation (3) is only true for a one dimensional wave. For three dimensional waves, the relation between wave number and wave is clearly shown in Eq. (1):

$K_x=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda_x}$

and so on.

Consider a 2D wave in cartesian coordinate system. Let the wave vector be $\vec{k}=(k_x,k_y)$. The wave vector is perpendicular to the direction of motion of waves, by definition. Let's say you observe these waves and you'd want to count number of waves per unit length in a particular direction. If you stand on the $x$-axis, you'd count $k_x$ number of waves, and $k_y$ if you stand on the $y$-axis. *If you look at the waves along the wave vector direction, you'd see $\lvert k \rvert$ number of waves*. Hence the formula $\lvert k \rvert = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$. The wavelength has to be measured along the direction of motion of the waves. Otherwise you'd see apparent wave length like $\lambda_x$, for which we have $k_x = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda_x}$ and so on.

Comment: According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_vector) Wikipedia article about wave vector, ($3$) is true for higher dimensional wave vectors as well.

Comment: Where is it mentioned in the Wikipedia article?

Comment: 'Crystallography definition' paragraph.

Comment: The definition of wave number essentially gives number of waves in unit length of space. Consider the box you're talking about. There could be different number of waves in each of the x,y,z directions, leading to different wave numbers.

Comment: I have seen other places as well a definition for wave vector that $\mathbf{k}=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\mathbf{\hat{n}},
 $ where $\hat{n}$ is a unit vector.

Comment: In the Wiki article, it's written $k=|\vec{k}|=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$. The _k_ they are referring to is from the first equation.

Comment: Also in 'In special relativity' section they use that and there it is clearly for 3D vector.

Comment: What is true is the relation between wave speed, frequency and wave number: $\omega^2=c^2 k^2$, here $k^2={k^2}_x+{k^2}_y+{k^2}_z$. There is no wave vector definition. But there is a definition for wave number vector. Check this [link](http://www.physics.usu.edu/riffe/3750/Lecture%2018.pdf).

Comment: [This](http://www.antenna-theory.com/definitions/wavevector.php) website also uses definition $ \mathbf{k}=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\mathbf{\hat{n}}
 $ for wave vector. Your link also says that $|\mathbf{k}|=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}
 $.